# Find the maximal solution of the ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Exercice :**
Find the maximal solution of the ODE : $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{t^2}\cos(\frac{1}{t})$$ such that $x(t_0)=c,$  and $t_0=\theta$ for $t<t_0.$

**My attempt :**
we have $\displaystyle dx=\dfrac{1}{t^2}\cos(\frac{1}{t}) \,dt$.
Let $\displaystyle u=\frac{1}{t}$, so $\displaystyle du=-\frac{dt}{t^2}$.

\begin{align*}\int \dfrac{1}{t^2}\cos(\frac{1}{t}) dt &=-\int u^2\frac{\cos(u)}{u^2}du \\&=-\int \cos(u)du \\&=-\sin(u)+k \\&=-\sin(\frac{1}{t})+k \end{align*}
so  $$x(t)=-\sin(\frac{1}{t}) +k$$
or $x(t_0)= -\sin(\frac{1}{t_0})+k=c$, thus $k=c+\sin(\frac{1}{t_0})$ .
finally $$x(t)=-\sin(\frac{1}{t}) +c+\sin(\frac{1}{t_0}) $$
then the maximal solution is $]-\infty,t_0[\setminus\{0\}$.
Is that true?? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, usually the maximal solution of an IVP is defined as in here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/Maximum_domain_of_solution . So when you say that $t <t_0$ do you mean that you want to find the maximal interval of definition $I$ intersected with $(-\infty,t_0)$?

Comment: yeah exactly ! Thank you @PAM1499

Comment: Hence notice your solution is defined for $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Then if $t_0$ is positive the maximal interval of definition is $I=(0,+\infty)$. And  if $t_0$ is negative the maximal interval of definition is $I=(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: what about the condition $t<t_0$ ?

Comment: Well, intersect the intervals with $(-\infty,t_0)$. At least this is what I understand you are looking for...

Comment: But notice (as pointed out in the link above) defining your solution in an interval that does not contain your initial condition $t_0$ makes no sense

Comment: yeah , ok thank you a lot !!

Comment: Glad to help! ;)